# how to build carousal using ng2-bootstrap without knowing how many image you want to use in advance?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, ng2-bootstrap

i am working on project using ASP.net Api and angular  and i want to build carousal using ng2 bootstrap but i dont know how many images i will? any suggestion how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of image urls, you can use the angular *ngFor syntax to loop through the images, causing the output to change depending on the array.

TypeScript: `let images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'];`

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div *ngFor="let image of images">
        <image [src]="image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check demo with source code http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/carousel
Pay attention how "add slide" button works, this is what you need to replicate